# How are Go closure capture rules distinct from defer?

Tags: go

The following Go code demonstrates a distinction in the closure-capture rules between defer and go closures. In a tutorial, I was told that for-loop variables have scope limited to the loop body, but something seems different here.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func deferred() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        defer fmt.Println(i)
    }
}

func cps() {
    clo := new(func())
    *clo = func() {}
    defer func() { (*clo)() }()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        oldClo := *clo
        *clo = func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
            oldClo()
        }
    }
}

func cpsCpy() {
    clo := new(func())
    *clo = func() {}
    defer func() { (*clo)() }()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        oldClo := *clo
        cpy := i
        *clo = func() {
            fmt.Println(cpy)
            oldClo()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("defer")
    deferred()
    fmt.Println("cps")
    cps()
    fmt.Println("cpsCpy")
    cpsCpy()
}
```

This produces output:

```
defer
4
3
2
1
0
cps
5
5
5
5
5
cpsCpy
4
3
2
1
0
```

If the difference is intentional, then what are the different use-cases that justify it?

Comment: There is no difference, you are seeing: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: @JimB Well, that FAQ makes it seem like a for loop creates two scopes, one for the iterator, and an inner one for the body. But then it still seems that defer *is* different: it's not creating a closure (as I think some places claim). It first does a weird value-based capture for non-reference-variables, then makes the closure, no?

Comment: Nope, the scope is the same in all cases. In `cps` you're just capturing the single `i` variable and printing it 5 times.

Comment: @JimB I'm afraid I'm still a bit confused. Could you perhaps write an answer, maybe expanding the for into a go "while" loop that demonstrates what exactly the scopes are? Why wouldn't defer capture the single i variable as well?

Comment: Yeah, @JimB is right that the behavior with the closure is the specified one. What defer's doing is not variable capture at all; it's specced to evaluate the function args and save them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [spec for defer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) is clear on this. The spec in general is crucial reading for anyone who cares about stuff like variable capture rules, and relatively short for what it is. What it says here is:

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked.

It's also covered in [the blog post on defer, panic, and recover](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).

It's always hard to justify design decisions to everyone's satisfaction, and the `defer` one in particular does surprise people now and then, notably when you do `defer f1(f2(x))` and forget `f2(x)` will be evaluated immediately.

One thing that may help remember it, though, is that what comes after `defer` (or `go`) is *a function call*, and just the function invocation itself (not even evaluation of params) is shifted in time. The closure defines a *block of code*, and accessing the variables happens when the code is executed.

---

Since you were curious about the use for the kind of variable capture you get with closures, one example of where it's useful is if you're using a closure with a method like `ForEach`:

```
myBTree.ForEach(func (key, value []byte) {
    //...
})
```

It's nice if, like in a regular `for` loop, the code between the braces can modify variables in the outer scope. That requires that the closure be accessing the variables, not just their values as of a specific time.

Comment: OK, so defer doesn't create a closure, it's this whole independent statement that has its own behavior and needs to be given individual attention.

To me it seems that the unjustifiable decision here is for closures to capture references (as opposed to using the parameter-like value capture except for reference types); this seems just like an error-prone way of saving people who intend this behavior to happen from writing an extra line creating a pointer.

Comment: So thank you for answering the first part of my question. Would you mind answering the second? I don't need to be convinced, but for my own knowledge I'd like to see when it's helpful to have the reference capture.

Comment: @VF1: defer isn't really special, it's that function arguments are always evaluated at the call point. It works the same if you defer a closure: https://play.golang.org/p/jLBlh1hEF1

Comment: @JimB Well, you're saying it's not special, but then qualifying why it is. Regardless of what the language calls it, it quacks like a closure, so it needs to be reasoned about as if it's a closure with different capture semantics for correctness. I'm saying two types of capture semantics is one too many, with the hope of seeing a motivating use case for the difference.

Comment: @VF1, a defer calls the function and the _evaluated_ argument when the outer function returns. That's all. I'm not sure how else to explain it, but it follows the same rules as any other function call. Maybe this helps show a little more explicitly what's happening? https://play.golang.org/p/pyZ7ft2l7D

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you may be asking why the _closure_ behavior ("reference capture") is useful, not why the defer behavior is. I may be able to briefly show how that can be useful, 1 min.

Comment: Imagine you've got something like `myBTree.ForEach(func(key, value []byte) {...})`. In terms of purpose, that closure body is like the body of a `for` loop. So, the most natural thing is for it to be able to modify vars in outer scopes of the function, like a `for` loop can. To do that it needs to have, in effect, references to those variables. It's probably better to search around for stuff about closure var capture (not necc. Go specific stuff) if you're more interested in the uses of closures and why they act as they do.

Comment: @twotwotwo OK, consistency with for-blocks for closures seems like a good enough reason to me. Thanks again.